# Unmountable HDD - Can I save the data?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

I have an iMac, and the internal HDD is failing.  My files are still there, and I'm able to login, but it freezes when I try to do anything.  I attempted to use asr in terminal to copy the entire Macintosh HD folder to an external HDD, but *facepalm* set the target as the WRONG HDD.  When I hit enter, asr went through it's normal steps, and then hit PSTT 0  100 start restore and hung there for longer than I expected it to.  Then I realized that I put the wrong target volume, and terminated the window.

Now, when I try to plug the HDD into my laptop, it doesn't mount.  I can see it in Disk Utility and can run repair on it, but get the following:

"Problems were found with the partition map, that may prevent booting"

Trying to mount it in the terminal fails too.

I have Disk Warrior, and it can see the HDD (and even shows the name I set for it, whereas Disk Utility shows it as Untitled) but it says the drive is too big.

I have Drive Genius, but it shows up under devices and not volumes, so I can't repair it there either.

Can anyone help me fix the map?

Details:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE PER @DAVIDANDERSON'S REQ:**

**sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1** results:

```
     start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2          4         Pri GPT table
          6      76800      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      76806  732331114      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  732407920     158720      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  732566640          4         Sec GPT table
  732566644          1         Sec GPT header
```

**results of sudo fdisk /dev/disk1:**

```
Disk: /dev/disk1    geometry: 45600/255/63 [732566645 sectors]
Sector size: 4096 bytes
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  732566644] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

**PARTITION STRUCTURE VIA TEST DISK**

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/rdisk1 - 3000 GB / 2794 GiB - 732566645 sectors
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 P EFI System                     6      76805      76800 [EFI System Partitio
No HFS or HFS+ structure
 2 P Mac HFS                    76806  732407919  732331114 [Holland Big Boy]
 2 P Mac HFS                    76806  732407919  732331114 [Holland Big Boy]
 3 P Mac Boot               732407920  732566639     158720 [Recovery HD]
```

**ADDL UPDATE: Analysis via TestDisk - see below for progress**

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/rdisk1 - 3000 GB / 2794 GiB - 732566645 sectors
Analyse sector   278102016/732566644: 00%


check_FAT: Unusual media descriptor (0xf0!=0xf8)
Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 16 (FAT) != 1 (HD)
Warning: number of sectors per track mismatches 32 (FAT) != 1 (HD)
  EFI System                     6      76805      76800 [EFI]
  Mac HFS                   156013  271598000  271441988
```

**TESTDISK UPDATE**
I have to stop the process prematurely - I brough tmy work laptop home to work on all of this, and unfortunately the scan didn't finish before I have to return to work.  Progress below:

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/rdisk1 - 3000 GB / 2794 GiB - 732566645 sectors
Analyse sector   296943616/732566644: 00%


check_FAT: Unusual media descriptor (0xf0!=0xf8)
Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 16 (FAT) != 1 (HD)
Warning: number of sectors per track mismatches 32 (FAT) != 1 (HD)
  EFI System                     6      76805      76800 [EFI]
  Mac HFS                   156013  271598000  271441988
  Mac HFS                280526626  282014439    1487814
  Unknown                285399261  791014120  505614859
  Mac HFS                288815421  288905227      89807
  Mac HFS                288931061  289023226      92166
  Mac HFS                289086265  289190956     104691
  Mac HFS                290295252  291221714     926463



  Stop
```

**UPDATE**
I bought Disk Drill, scanned the drive, and was able to retrieve my files, copying now (3 days!!!!! ugh!!!!).  Disk Drill categorized the found files by type - video/pictures/audio/etc and dumped all file name info - they're now file 000001.jpg etc.  So I've lost file names and folder structure.  I'm so grateful and happy to be able to have my files back, now hoping there's a way to get my structure/names back on the old drive...  Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: I suppose if there is something wrong with the partition map, you should attempt to print out the values in the tables. To to do so you will need to execute the following commands. `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1` and `sudo fdisk /dev/disk1` These commands will not change your drive. If the commands will not execute, then let me know and I will instruct you on how to do a hex dump of the table values.

Comment: Hi!  Thank you for your help - I read through an answer that you helped someone else with, but unfortunately we didn't have the same problem...  So happy to see you here!!!

Comment: Yes, I need to be able to get it off and onto a new drive

Comment: @Lauren If I understand your question correctly, you have one internal faulty drive and at least two external drives. You wanted to asr to the empty external drive1 but targeted the also attached data drive 2 instead? What is the size of the internal iMac drive? Do you remember the complete `asr ...` command?

Comment: Correct! iMac drive is 1TB, wanted to copy to a 2TB ext, but accidentally copied to 3TB ext that had all of my files on it.  The coast command was --noverify --erase --verbose --source source --target target.  It only got the the PSTT 0 100 start restore step, but just hung there.  Then I looked over the commands I sent, realized my error, and quit the window. I hope the files are still there, and that I just can't mount it because the map is trashed.  I hope that if it really was erased, I wouldn't be able to see the drive name in Disk Warrior

Comment: The asr command**

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and I'm leaving my solution here in case someone else has the same issue:

I bought Disk Drill ($90 for the Pro version). Had it go through all recovery options for the drive (took 6 hours for a 3TB drive), which resulted in a list of files, organized by file type and without file info.

For example, all of my JPGs were in one folder, with names like file00001.jpg, file00002.jpg, etc.

I saved the session, went back, and had it search for lost HFS partitions and **all my folders and file names** are back.

**UPDATE**
I started transferring my files over to a new drive, and unfortunately none of them are readable.  All of them throw an error that says the file is either empty, or damaged/corrupted.  Taking a couple steps back and transferring over the deep scan files instead - the unnamed/sorted-by-file-type versions.  Although those don't have any organizational data, they are not damaged.

Any ideas of how I can recover my files WITH information intact would be much appreciated...  Or a way to salvage the map of the original drive.

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1` (the recovered disk) to this **answer**! Be sure the 3 TB drive is the only attached external drive or the disk identifier (/dev/diskX with X = 1, 2, etc.) may be different

Comment: @klanomath Here is the info requested: `start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2          4         Pri GPT table
          6      76800      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      76806  732331114      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  732407920     158720      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  732566640          4         Sec GPT table
  732566644          1         Sec GPT header`